Looking for book I read once about half elf and dwarf protagonist
Things I can remember:

mc is half dwarf half elf

has an adoptive father who does blacksmithing.

in this world women can use magic alright, but in order for men to use magic they need to go through a painful procedure that makes them sterile

knights in this book wear massive armor to protect from magic

mc gets conscripted for war

mc is really strong and amazing with the bow

mc has a thing about stomping on enemies feet and punching them whilst they can't move

mc ends up being trained by a mage and a knight



When and where did you read it or when do you think it was published? Is it in English? Any other details about book or cover would be helpful.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/14656503-the-brotherhood-of-dwarves perhaps?

Afraid not, but that book does look good so thanks for the suggestion

Dragonlance series?

Which half was the elf and which half was the dwarf?

Mother was an elf and the dad was the dwarf

Not dragon lance series either, but definitely going to give that one a try
